# Predicate giving different output than the one intended

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have a predicate called `stop_when_equal` that works like this:

```
stop_when_equal(L1, L2):-
    Pred1(L1, L2),L1==L2, ! ;
    Pred1(L1, L2),stop_when_equal(L2,_).
```

Basically it keeps applying `Pred1` to `L1` until no changes are made. If i use a `writeln()` here,:

```
stop_when_equal(L1, L2):-
    Pred1(L1, L2),L1==L2,writeln(L2), ! ;
    Pred1(L1, L2),stop_when_equal(L2,_).
```

It writes what is intended, but the output comes out differently! I know that Pred1 is working correctly since if I apply it over and over it eventually gives me the correct output,but i need a predicate that does this task for me. Whats the error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, I hav to make sure this is correctly parenthesized.

```
?- write_canonical( ( stop_when_equal(L1, L2):- pred1(L1, L2),L1==L2, ! ; pred1(L1, L2),stop_when_equal(L2,_) ) ).

:-(stop_when_equal(A,B),;(','(pred1(A,B),','(==(A,B),!)),','(pred1(A,B),stop_when_equal(B,_))))
```

Okay.

Can you add an explanation on "the output comes out differently"?

Trying:

```
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots
pred1(L1,L2) :- L2 is 0.5 * (L1 + 2.0 / L1). 

stop_when_equal(L1, L2):-
    (pred1(L1, L2),
     debug(swe,"L1=~q, L2=~q",[L1,L2]),
     L1==L2, !) % what happens if this branch backtracks over pred1(L1,L2)??
    ;               
    (debug(swe,"Recursion",[]),
     pred1(L1, L2),
     stop_when_equal(L2,_)). % Doing nothing with he result?
```

Works for me

```
?- debug(swe),stop_when_equal(0.5,L).
% L1=0.5, L2=2.25
% Recursion
% L1=2.25, L2=1.5694444444444444
% Recursion
% L1=1.5694444444444444, L2=1.4218903638151426
% Recursion
% L1=1.4218903638151426, L2=1.4142342859400734
% Recursion
% L1=1.4142342859400734, L2=1.4142135625249321
% Recursion
% L1=1.4142135625249321, L2=1.414213562373095
% Recursion
% L1=1.414213562373095, L2=1.414213562373095
L = 2.25.
```

Seems to work.

Comment: I have found a way before coming back here to check the answers . Thanks for the answer anyway!